# git extensions causing visual studio buttons to disappear

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-2008, git-extensions

I have VS 2008 installed and have put Git and Git Extensions on my system.  I'm running Windows 7.  When I launch my VS and work, the buttons will go grey.  If I run the mouse pointer over them, they show up again.  If I minimize the window and bring it back up, they are there.  If I click on one of the buttons, it works as expected.  I'm trying to get other engineers to start using this tool, but this concerns them as to why it's happening.  Has anyone else seen this and does anyone have any idea how to get it to stop happening?
Thanks,
Richard

Comment: Same behavior on my machine (WinXP, VS2008). Also VS is getting extremly slow. Dragging the Git toolbar is also extremly slow. Does anyone knows why or has a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same behavior with Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012.
*Disabling the GitExtension toolbar resolves the issue.*
I have this issue only with projects without GIT repository.

Comment: Yes, it seems really to happen only with projects that are **not** under source control.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the GitExtensions toolbar solved the issue for me. You can still use the add-in from the Git menu item in the Visual Studio menu bar. To disable it right-click the toolbar area and uncheck the checkbox next to the GitExtensions item.

Before I disabled the GitExtensions toolbar Visual Studio was unresponsive whenever I maximized or restored the size of the main window. I think this is a bug in the add-in. The VS2008 version seems to be pretty old and I'm not experiencing unresponsive behavior in VS2010 where a newer version is available.